# Google Play Games doesn't work with app published in PlayStore

Tags: android, release, google-play-games

So I built an app and implemented Leaderboards with Google Play Games Services.

If I install the app via adb, the service functions as intended.

If I install the app via the PlayStore, as Release, Beta, Alpha or internal test, I cannot use the services. Logcat doesn't give me any errors. If I want to check the Leaderboard it just says "Hmm, something went wrong in Play Games".

So most of the pages in the internet say that I should clear my cache, or I have a wrong SHA1-key configured. First thing doesn't help. I cleared the cache of my game and the play games app. Didn't worked.

So I checked the SHA1-keys. In the google developer console, my release key is under upload certificate. So that seems fine. Under App-signature, there is the key from google. I checked Firebase, and there is Google Play Games API activated with the key from Google.

So that also seems right. Do you have any ideas? I am working on this for 3 days now. Checked lots of stuff from the internet and nothing works.

If you need any information, feel free to ask.

**EDIT:**

If I install the app over the app-store, I can check the leaderboard just as normal and the the entries I made earlier with my self installed app version. Until I play a game and send a new score to the leaderboard. From this moment on, the "Hmm, something went wrong" message comes instead of the leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i found that the sha-1 key from the google cert was used with a wrong app-id. I couldn't change the key for the right app-id which was used by me. It said that the key is already used. Even if i deleted the wrong app-id with the right cert. SO i followed this:
[The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565332/the-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-an-android-oauth2-client-id-in)
That solved my problem.
So basically i deleted all the client-ids in the API settings of the play console and relinked the app. Now everything works.
I hope this will help someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the same problem that you had. Could you please list the exact steps that you did to fix your problem? How did you relink the app? From what I understood the steps are: 
1. delete all OAuth2 client ids of type 'Android' (in Google APIs & services) [does the OAuth2 web client id also need to be deleted ?]
2. unpublish the linked game (in the Developer Console) 
3. create a new linked game and enter the sha-1 key of the release keystore (in the Developer Console)
Is this what fixed your problem? I am stuck with my problem: [Message in Leaderboard: "Hmm, something went wrong in Play Games"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164643/message-in-leaderboard-hmm-something-went-wrong-in-play-games) and hence would like to know what you did to resolve yours. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey. I didn't unpublish my game. But you can do so. I just followed the steps of the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565332/the-fingerprint-you-specified-is-already-used-by-an-android-oauth2-client-id-in so follow those four steps and it should work. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project/{your-project-id} and select APIs & auth > Credentials. There is "Client ID for Android Allication". Click the delete button there. Now go to the dev console and link your game. That should fix the problem. If not, contact. me.

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my problem. :))