# Message in Leaderboard: "Hmm, something went wrong in Play Games"

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I added Google Play Games Services support to my board game app and implemented Achievements and a Leaderboard through the corresponding clients in a similar way as the GPGS sample app "Type A Number" did. When debugging with adb and my tester account, these features worked fine. When I released the app into production, the Leaderboard started showing the message "Hmm, something went wrong in Play Games". Additionally, achievements can be unlocked and are being shown properly. But after closing the app, this progress is being lost.

Under Google APIs -> Google Play Games Services I get this feedback of the GPGS API calls (in the production phase):

[GPGS method calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQEAE.png)

Since the release, I apparently mainly get 401 as a response code according to the metrics.

SOLUTION: [Google Play Games doesn't work with app published in PlayStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55143349/google-play-games-doesnt-work-with-app-published-in-playstore)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue - it looks like Play Services do not work correctly for the testers atm. I have the app that is live and an update which is in closed Alpha. Tested with the test account with the same issue. Then tried the same closed alpha update (previously installed by test user) with the user who is not listed as tester and Services worked fine. Didn't push the update live though - will update when it's live and Play Services status is rechecked.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Leaderboards stopped appearing after first post. I tried removing OAuth keys and putting them back on, but that didn't seem to do the job. Went for a hail mary and linked the same app AGAIN to Games Services and voila! Image below shows what to do. Worked for me, hope it works for you. Cheers!

[image: Google Play Console > Game Services > Link App > Link Another App]